# How to update my score?

Tags: python, pygame

My program works fine but I can't update the score. This is for my project; I am on the last part and cant figure it out myself. I pasted the whole code for reference.

```
import pygame
import random

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
betmoney = 100
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def menu():
    done = True
    while done:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    tracks()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_F1:
                    about()
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()


        game_S.blit(bg, [0,0])
        for i in range (30):
            x = random.randrange(0, 700)
            y = random.randrange(0, 700)
            pygame.draw.circle(game_S, GREEN, [x,y], 5)
            pygame.display.update()

        game_S.blit(text, [170, 450])
        pygame.display.flip()
        game_S.blit(betm, [0,0])
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(10)

def win():
    while True:
        game_S.blit(winner, [0,0])
        game_S.blit(text, [170, 450])
        game_S.blit(betm, [0, 0])
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    menu()

            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

    clock.tick(10)

def loser():
    while True:
        game_S.blit(lose, [0,0])
        game_S.blit(text, [170, 450])
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    menu()

            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

    clock.tick(10)

def tracks ():
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    game_S.blit(track3, [0,0])
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    game_S.blit(track2, [0,0])
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    game_S.blit(track1, [0,0])
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    game_S.blit(trackgo, [0,0])
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(1000)
    game_S.fill(WHITE)
    game_S.blit(track, [0,0])
    pygame.display.update()
    game_S.blit(bet, [0, 230])
    game_S.blit(en1, [0, 20])
    game_S.blit(en2, [0, 80])
    game_S.blit(en3, [0, 160])
    game_S.blit(en4, [0, 295])
    game_S.blit(en5, [0, 360])
    game_S.blit(en6, [0, 440])
    pygame.display.update
    pygame.display.flip()
    r1 = random.randrange(1,10)
    r2 = random.randrange(1,10)
    r3 = random.randrange(1,10)
    r4 = random.randrange(1,10)
    r5 = random.randrange(1,10)
    r6 = random.randrange(1,10)
    racemode(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,0)

def racemode(a,b,c,d,e,f,wow):
    move = True

    while move:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and wow <= 600:
                    game_S.blit(bet, [wow, 230])
                    wow +=5
                    pygame.display.update()
                    clock.tick(10)
                    continue
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

        if a<= 600:
            game_S.blit(en1, [a,20])
            a += random.randrange(10,15)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(30)

        if b<= 600:
            game_S.blit(en2, [b,80])
            b +=random.randrange(10,15)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(30)

        if c<= 600:
            game_S.blit(en3, [c,160])
            c += random.randrange(10,15)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(30)

        if d<= 600:
            game_S.blit(en4, [d,295])
            d+= random.randrange(10,15)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(30)

        if e<= 600:
            game_S.blit(en5, [e,360])
            e+= random.randrange(10,15)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(30)

        if f<=600:
            game_S.blit(en6, [f,440])
            f+=random.randrange(10,15)
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(30)

        if wow >= 600 and a <600 and b <600 and c<600 and d<600 and e<600 and f<600:
            win()
        elif wow < 600 and a>= 600 or b>=600 or c>= 600 or d >= 600 or e >= 600 or f >=600:
            loser()



def about():
    tan = True
    game_S.fill(WHITE)
    game_S.blit(ab, [0,0])
    pygame.display.update()
    texts = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 35, True, False)
    fonts = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 30, True, False)
    tput1 = texts.render("ABOUT THE BETTING SYSTEM", True, BLACK)
    tput2 = fonts.render("-> You are given $100 as starting money", True, RED)
    tput3 = fonts.render("-> You can get +100 if you win" , True, RED)
    tput3b = fonts.render("-> You will lose 100 if you lose", True, RED)
    tput4 = fonts.render("-> You beat the game when you reach 1000", True, RED)
    tput5 = fonts.render("-> GAME OVER if you got $0 money", True, RED)
    back = font.render(" PRESS F1 to go Back", True, BLACK)
    game_S.blit(tput1, [120,80])
    pygame.display.update()
    game_S.blit(tput2, [100,150])
    pygame.display.update()
    game_S.blit(tput3, [100,200])
    pygame.display.update()
    game_S.blit(tput3b, [100,250])
    pygame.display.update()
    game_S.blit(tput4, [100,300])
    pygame.display.update()
    game_S.blit(tput5, [100,350])
    pygame.display.update()

    while tan:
        game_S.blit(back, [170,450])
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_F1:
                    menu()

            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

    clock.tick(10)

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (700, 500)
game_S = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("BET ON YOUR TURTLE")
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 34, True, False)
text = font.render("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE", True, RED)
betm = font.render(str(betmoney), 1, RED)







#---IMAGES----
bg = pygame.image.load("kim.png")
ab = pygame.image.load("waw.png")
bet = pygame.image.load("witwew.png").convert_alpha()
en1 = pygame.image.load("enemy1.png")
en2 = pygame.image.load("enemy2.png")
en3 = pygame.image.load("enemy3.png")
en4 = pygame.image.load("enemy4.png")
en5 = pygame.image.load("enemy5.png")
en6 = pygame.image.load("enemy6.png")
track = pygame.image.load("TRACK.png")
track3 = pygame.image.load("TRACK3.png")
track2 = pygame.image.load("TRACK2.png")
track1 = pygame.image.load("TRACK1.png")
trackgo = pygame.image.load("TRACKGO.png")
winner = pygame.image.load("winner.png")
lose = pygame.image.load("lose.png")
#--IMAGES (end)--

pygame.mixer.music.load("icecream_8bit.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

menu()
```

You can see that I put betmoney as local variable with 100 value and don't know how to add 100 or deduct 100.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Although I don't use Python, the sheer size of this suggests that some debugging would be necessary to create a smaller example of the problem. Would you try narrowing it down?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about accessing the "betmoney" variable that come to mind. Firstly, simply pass it into the function that you plan on accessing it as an argument. This is generally the preferred way. Second, simply declare "betmoney" a global variable and it can be accessed from anywhere.